# Convert this NHibernate query with queryover

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have some problem to convert this NHibernate queries into the left join queryover

```
var query = session.Query<T>.Join(
    Session.Query<RecordOrder>(),
    q=>q.MiniDbName,
    o=>o.DatabaseName,
    (q,o)=>new{Record = q, Order = o.OrderValue})
```

Anyone can help me, I want this query support the left join.

Comment: Specifically, what problems are you having?

Comment: I want to change this query to be like this SQL : "SELECT o.Order,o.Record FROM Record r LEFT JOIN Order o ON r.MiniDbName = o.DatabaseName

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default join is an inner-join. Each of the additional join types can be specified using the methods .Inner, .Left, .Right, or .Full. For example, to left outer-join on Kittens use:

```
IQueryOver<Cat,Kitten> catQuery =
session.QueryOver<Cat>()
    .Left.JoinQueryOver(c => c.Kittens)
        .Where(k => k.Name == "Tiddles");
```

In your case :

```
    var list =
    session.QueryOver<RecordOrder>()
    .Left.JoinQueryOver(c => c.Orders).ToList()
```